# base-point free pullback

Tags: algebraic-geometry, divisors-algebraic-geometry

I want to use some kind of the following property of base-point freeness:

> Let $f: X \longrightarrow Y$ be a morphism and $D$ a Cartier divisor on Y. If $|f^* D|$ is base-point free then $|D|$ is base-point free.

Is this always true? Any additional assumption for this to be true will be helpful.

Comment: No, this need not be true. Let $X\subset Y$ be any subvariety which misses the base point locus of $|D|$ and let $f$ be the inclusion $X\to Y$. With some more context on where you're trying to use this, perhaps we could be more helpful.